# No focus on dynamically added textbox

Tags: jquery, html

Each time I click a button a new text box is added, I want the textbox to have focus on load. If I click the button again I want the focus to shift to the newly added textbox.

- Tried autofocus but it works for just the 1st time.
- Tried $("#xyz").focus() too but its not working
  either.

Comment: `but it works for just the 1st element not for the next elements.` How can we set focus to more than 1 element at the same time?

Comment: *I want the textbox to have focus on load* Do you mean focus on textbox after creating?

Comment: Please display us your code

Comment: Could you please post your Javascript code that is adding textbox dynamically

Comment: @TânNguyễn I want the focus to shift to newly added textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you meant correctly, you're looking for something like this example:

```js
$('button').on('click', function () {
  var textBox = $('<input type="text">');
  
  textBox.appendTo('body');
  
  var interval = setInterval(function () {
    textBox.focus();
    
    if (textBox.is(':focus')) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button">Add textbox</button>
```

After appending new input to body tag, we set `focus` to the element. But sometimes it is NOT focused immediately, so we need to use `setInterval` to check the focusing again after 100 miliseconds. Then, when the element is focused, we clear the interval via using `clearInterval` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example that achieves what you're after. In this example an input field is added after an existing input field and it is set to be focused using [focus()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp) function.

```js
let newInput = document.createElement( "input" );
newInput.setAttribute( "type", "text" );


let previousInput = document.getElementById( "test" );
previousInput.parentNode.insertBefore( newInput, previousInput.nextElementSibling );

newInput.focus();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test">
```

I hope this helps you.